# Spring SOAP Service accepts username/password: how to require that info via WSDL?

Tags: spring, soap, wsdl

I have a SOAP service implemented using Spring. The service accepts the username/password via the `<UsernameToken>` element in the SOAP header. That all works fine.

However, the client consuming this SOAP service requests that I include in the WSDL file that the username/password is required via a `<Policy>` in the `<wsdl:binding>` element.

I have a method in my code like:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class SoapWebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema s) {
        var wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("MyPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/soap");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://myservice.com/");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(s);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    ...
}
```

This produces a WSDL file, but without information in it that the `<UsernameToken>` is required.

How can I persuade Spring to include the necessary `<Policy>` information in the WSDL file?

I have looked at the Spring documentation but was unable to determine the incantation necessary. I have looked through the Spring source code but was also not able to see an obvious hook to add the extra information. What I am looking for is something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19726325/220627 but for Spring.

Answer (score 0):

What I do now is a bit of a hack, but I'll put it here in case it's helpful for someone. I'll leave the question open in the hope that someone comes along with a better solution!

```
private Source addWsdlUsernameTokenPolicy(@Source xml) {
    try {
        var originalDocumentDOMResult = new DOMResult();
        var transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(xml, originalDocumentDOMResult);

        var doc = (Document) originalDocumentDOMResult.getNode();

        // ... alter the document using DOM methods as necessary ...

        return new DOMSource(doc);
    } 
    catch (TransformerConfigurationException | TransformerException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Bean
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema s) {
    var wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition() {

        // This is the trick. The getSource() returns the XML of the WSDL.
        // You can convert this "Source" (of XML) into a DOM XML structure
        // then alter the XML as you like with normal DOM operations.
        @Override public Source getSource() {
            return addWsdlUsernameTokenPolicy(super.getSource()); 
        }
    };
    ...
    return wsdl11Definition;
}
```